# Connecting to AWS Neptune

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, graph-databases, amazon-vpc, amazon-neptune

In the official aws neptune documentation they have mentioned that we can connect to neptune outside vpc but a security group has to be defined for that. Though somewhere it is mentioned that you cannot connect to it from outside vpc and if want to connect then it is only possible through EC2. 
So now I am a bit confused and want to know can we connect to AWS Neptune from outside VPC but not through EC2 via a Java application running on any server or local?

Comment: Could you link the relevant sections in the official docs which according to you contradict each other? Thanks

Comment: 'https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/limits.html' that says ' VPC Required
Amazon Neptune is a virtual private cloud (VPC)–only service. Additionally, instances do not allow access from outside the VPC.' and 'https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/get-started-prerequisites.html' that says 'Before you create a Neptune DB instance, you must have an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC). If you want to access your Neptune DB instance from outside the VPC, you must also have a security group for the VPC with rules that allow you to connect to the Neptune DB instance.'

Comment: @Darpana The contradicting lines are no longer mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs -

> Access from the internet is allowed only to the EC2 instance. The EC2 instance is allowed access to the graph database.

Maybe the below diagram clears things up a little up

[image]

Your Java application that directly connects to the NeptuneDB should be hosted on a sever within the VPC.

You can however make connections to this server from outside the VPC if you choose to.

Hope this answers your questions.

P.S -

> Additionally, instances do not allow access from outside the VPC.

The term instance in above statement refers to the NeptuneDB instance not any ec2 instance within the VPC